# Prove the property of the dot product of the vectors: $\bf u(v_{1} + v_{2} \cdots v_{n}) = uv_{1} + uv_{2} \cdots + uv_{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> **Proposition.** $$\bf u(v_{1} + v_{2} \cdots v_{n}) = uv_{1} +  uv_{2} \cdots +  uv_{n}$$
>   where $\bf u$ and $\bf v_{1},v_{2},\cdots, v_{n}$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^{m}$

My second attempt:

---

Before moving on, notes on notation:

I will denote $i$th element of $j$th vector as $ v_{(j),(i)}$, e.g:

The fifth element of the $\bf v_{3}$ is denoted as $v_{(3),(5)}$

---

All vectors are in  $\mathbb R^{m}$

We have $$\mathbf{u} = \begin {pmatrix}
u_{1} \\   
u_{2} \\
\vdots \\
u_{m} \end {pmatrix} $$

And

$$ \bf(v_{1} + v_{2} \cdots v_{n}) = 
\begin {pmatrix}
v_{(1),(1)} \\   
v_{(1),(2)} \\
\vdots \\
v_{(1),(m)} \end {pmatrix}
+
\begin {pmatrix}
v_{(2),(1)} \\   
v_{(2),(2)} \\
\vdots \\
v_{(2),(m)} \end {pmatrix}
+
\cdots
+
\begin {pmatrix}
v_{(n),(1)} \\   
v_{(n),(2)} \\
\vdots \\
v_{(n),(m)} \end {pmatrix}
=
\begin {pmatrix}
v_{(1),(1)} + v_{(2),(1)} + \cdots + v_{(n),(1)} \\   
v_{(1),(2)} + v_{(2),(2)} + \cdots + v_{(n),(2)} \\
\vdots \\
v_{(1),(m)} + v_{(2),(m)} + \cdots + v_{(n),(m)}  \end {pmatrix} $$

We can rewrite vector $\bf(v_{1} + v_{2} \cdots v_{n})$ in a more compact form

$$\mathbf{(v_{1} + v_{2} \cdots v_{n})} =
\begin {pmatrix} 
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}v_{(i),(1)}\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}v_{(i),(2)}\\
\vdots \\
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}v_{(i),(m)}
\end {pmatrix}$$

The dot product of the $\bf u$ and $\bf (v_{1} + v_{2} \cdots v_{n})$ is

$$\mathbf{u^{T}(v_{1} + v_{2} \cdots v_{n})} = (u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_{m})
\begin {pmatrix} 
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}v_{(i),(1)}\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}v_{(i),(2)}\\
\vdots \\
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}v_{(i),(m)}
\end {pmatrix} = u_{1}\sum_{i=1}^n v_{(i),(1)} + u_{2}\sum_{i=1}^n v_{(i),(2)} + \cdots + u_{m}\sum_{i=1}^n v_{(i),(m)} = $$
$$ = \sum_{k=1}^{m}u_{k}\sum_{i=1}^n v_{(i),(k)}$$

Applying property of the summation
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}u_{k}\sum_{i=1}^n v_{(i),(k)} = \sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^n u_{k} v_{(i),(k)} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{m}u_{k} v_{(i),(k)}$$

Which can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{m}u_{k} v_{(i),(k)} = \bigl(u_{1}v_{(1),(1)} + u_{2}v_{(1),(2)} + \cdots + u_{m}v_{(1),(m)}\bigr)
+\bigl(u_{1}v_{(2),(1)} + u_{2}v_{(2),(2)} + \cdots + u_{m}v_{(2),(m)}\bigr) + \cdots + \bigl(u_{1}v_{(n),(1)} + u_{2}v_{(n),(2)} + \cdots + u_{m}v_{(n),(m)}\bigr) = \bf uv_{1} + uv_{2} + \cdots + uv_{n}$$

$\Box$

Is it correct?

---

Comment: I think the way you are doing dot products on the matrix is wrong. How are you multiplying m × 1 matrix to another m × 1 matrix, if it is a matrix. (Note there is a transpose in the definition of dot product) .Also please mention the dimension of the vector space on which $v_i$ belongs and please clarify if u is a vector of scalar of some field.

Comment: @KNilesh Maybe I'm misunderstanding the definition of the dot product. Suppose we have vector $ a = (a_{1}, a_{2})^{T}$ and $b = (b_{1},b_{2})^{T}$, then the dot product is $a_{1}b_{1} + a_{2}b_{2}$ Is it incorrect?

Comment: yes, in fact, $\vc{x} \cdot \vc{y}=$ $\begin{align*}
  \vc{x}^T \vc{y} =   \left[
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
      x_1&
      x_2&
      x_3&
      \cdots&
      x_n
    \end{array}
  \right]
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      y_1\\
      y_2\\
      y_3\\
      \vdots\\
      y_n
    \end{array}
  \right]
  =x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3 + \ldots + x_ny_n = \vc{x} \cdot \vc{y}.
\end{align*}$

Comment: What @KNilesh is calling out is that you’ve expressed the dot product as a matrix product between matrices with incompatible shapes. You either need to include the $\cdot$ in all of the dot products or write them as $\mathbf u^T\mathbf v$.

Comment: No, it is not incorrect. But it is incorrect to write it as a matrix multiplication in the way you did. $\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ \ldots\\u_m\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ \ldots\\v_m\end{pmatrix}$ is not defined, you can't multiply these matrices in general. However $u^Tv=\begin{pmatrix}u_1& \ldots &u_m\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ \ldots\\v_m\end{pmatrix}$ is defined and yields the correct dot product.

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: @PauloMourão please check your edit. (The place you have put transpose sign)

Comment: @KNilesh Is there anything else wrong besides notation?

Comment: @KNilesh I'm sorry, where did I put a transpose sign? I thought I just corrected some $v_m$'s that should have been $u_m$'s

Comment: @Nelver your proof is correct. I don't think there is any flaw in it.

Comment: @PauloMourão , Nelver corrected it.

Comment: Oh okay. My bad

Answer (score 1):

It's easier (IMHO) to avoid matrices and just use coordinates: suppose $\mathbf{v_i} = (v_{i,1},\ldots, v_{i,m})$ for $i=1,\ldots n$, and $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,\ldots, u_m)$.

Then $$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{v_1}+\ldots+\mathbf{v_m})= \sum_{j=1}^m u_j \cdot (\mathbf{v_1}+\ldots+\mathbf{v_m})_j = \sum_{j=1}^m u_j \sum_{i=1}^n v_{i,j}$$

and $$\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{u}\mathbf{v_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m u_{j} v_{i,j}$$

and both are just the same double sum in a different order.