# Prove $\bf A(v_{1} + v_{2} + \cdots + v_n) = Av_{1} + Av_{2} + \cdots + Av_{n} $; $\bf A$ is matrix and $\bf v_{1},v_{2}... v_{n}$ are vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Proposition

> Let $\bf v_{1},v_{2},\cdots, v_{n}$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^{m}$ and $\bf A$ be a matrix of appropriate size so multiplication is valid. Prove
>
> $$\bf A(v_{1} + v_{2} + \cdots + v_n) = Av_{1} + Av_{2} + \cdots + Av_{n} $$

---

Notation:

$jth$ element of $i$th vector will be defined as $v_{(i),(j)}$, i.e:

6th element of the $\bf v_{5}$ is denoted as $v_{(5),(6)}$

---

Let $\bf A$ be $q$ by $m$ matrix

Let's consider arbitrary entry of the vector $$\bf A(v_{1} + v_{2} + \cdots + v_n)$$

Say, $j$

$$\biggl(\mathbf {A(v_{1} + v_{2} + \cdots + v_n)}\biggr)_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{j,i}\sum_{k=1}^nv_{(k),(i)} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{k=1}^na_{j,i}v_{(k),(i)} = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{j,i}v_{(k),(i)}$$

And for $$\biggl(\mathbf{ Av_{1} + Av_{2} + \cdots + Av_{n}}\biggr)_{j} = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{j,i}v_{(k),(i)} $$

We can see that $j$th entry of both vectors is identical. Since we've considered arbitrary entry, we can conclude that *all* corresponding entries of the two vectors are identical, and therefore:

$$\bf A(v_{1} + v_{2} + \cdots + v_n) = Av_{1} + Av_{2} + \cdots + Av_{n} $$

$\Box$

Is it correct?

---

This is *very* similar to the [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363222/prove-the-property-of-the-dot-product-of-the-vectors-bf-uv-1-v-2-cdot/3363251#3363251) I've proved before, but I believe there is still a possibility for mistake

Comment: To begin with, it suffices to show the case $n=2$ and then use induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, but you could also do it in $2$ smaller, and more general steps.

First, you can just show that the multiplication by matrix is linear, i.e. $\forall u,v$ vectors and $\lambda$ scalar, we have that $A(\lambda v)= \lambda A v$ and $A(u+v)=Au+Av$.

After that, you can show that every linear operator "behaves nicely" on finite sums, i.e. if $f$ is a linear operator, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ are appropriate vectors (i.e. $f$ is a linear operator from the vector space they are in), then
$$f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \right)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(v_i)$$
with induction.